# How do you change the authentication method on SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-authentication

I've deployed an SSIS project using the "SA" account to my SQL Server.  When I run a package from the SQL Server I am getting the error saying I need to use Integrated Authentication. I corrected the problem in Visual Studio (I changed it to use Windows Authentication) and the packages work fine there. When I redeploy them to my SQL Server, the authentication method didn't change. It won't even let me delete the packages or the project on SQL Server giving me the message that I can't delete using SQL Server authentication. How am I supposed to update the authentication method?

I am finding SSIS so problematic that I'm considering just replacing my data transfer packages with a C# program.

Comment: You *can't* run an SSIS Package with a login using SQL Authentication. you **must** connect using an Windows Authentication account.

Comment: Larnu, I already changed the connection manager to use Windows Authentication.  I was having trouble updating the connection manager on SQL Server.  See my solution below.

Comment: I didn't say anything about the connection manager. You need to **execute** the package with Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I had to shut down SQL Server Management Studio and then open it using Windows Authentication instead of SQL Authentication.  All works now.

Comment: Which is exactly what I said in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67878997/how-do-you-change-the-authentication-method-on-ssis?noredirect=1#comment119978918_67878997).